# How can i change google map marker for direction using iFrame?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed, google-maps-urls

Existing code:

`<iframe width="600" height="500" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=23.6000004,108.0333023&saddr=23.585941, 108.063190&daddr=23.620677, 108.05339+to:23.602400, 108.013489+to:@&z=13&output=embed"></iframe>`

[AS IS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpEsv.png)

[image]

[TO BE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnrcQ.png)

[image]

or someting noticeable than as is image

Comment: Where did you get the iframe frome? Please provide the code for it and some more information.

Comment: `<iframe width="600" height="500" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=23.6000004,108.0333023&saddr=23.585941, 108.063190&daddr=23.620677, 108.05339+to:23.602400, 108.013489+to:@&z=13&output=embed"></iframe>`

Comment: You can't modify the "free" iframes saved from Google.  You need to use one of their APIs (with a paid key) if you want to make modifications.

Comment: Can you give me a link for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [guide](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) on how to embed a map in your application from the Google Maps (maps.google.com) site. You should get something like this wherein you can copy the HTML code generated and paste it in your site.

[image: Embed a map]

Another option is to use the **[Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)** of the Google Maps Platform which lets you place an interactive map, or Street View panorama on your site with a simple HTTP request. *Note that you need to create a Maps project, enable billing and get an API key first before you can use the Maps Platform APIs. These are also indicated in the public doc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already have HTML code my problem is I want to customize the marker to my HTML code

Comment: I see. Customizing markers using Maps Embed API is not currently supported. If you are interested to have this feature, you can file this as feature request in Google's Public Issue Tracker:
https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker. Some other options for the meantime would be [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) or the [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) whichever suits your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

REMOVE +

Follow This Code :

"https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=23.6000004,108.0333023&saddr=-10.1630425,123.6226121&daddr=-10.1546409,123.6622598&to:23.602400,108.013489&to:@&z=13&output=embed"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).